# How to call function in MVC style programming?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

Okay so here is one of my classes in my Model package:

```
package accountManager.model;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import accountManager.view.JFrame;

public class AccountModel extends AbstractModel{
public String [] getInfo() throws IOException {

    FileReader in = new FileReader("data");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

    //List<String> lines = new Array<String>();
    String line;
    int num_lines = 0;

    String[] accountData = new String[5];

    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        accountData[num_lines] = line;
        num_lines++;
        //System.out.println(line);
    }
    return accountData;
}
```

}

Here is where I'm trying to call a function to place an array from the function into a JComboBox, but I don't know how to properly call it and am pretty sure I am doing it wrong...

```
JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(((AccountModel)model).getInfo());
    comboBox.setBounds(135, 30, 140, 20);
    contentPane.add(comboBox);
```

I also imported these two into my Jframe which holds the JComboBox:

```
import accountManager.model.AccountModel;
import accountManager.model.Model;
```

I just don't know what I am doing, I am very new to java. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your controller? MVC = model-view-controller. You have your model, you have your view, where is your controller? Normally, you call the model functions in your controller and you pass the data that you get from these functions to the view. The controller is the glue between the model and the view.

You can go a step further and use the pubsub pattern. This promotes loose coupling. Add your view as a subscriber to the controller, the publisher, and call the appropiate functions via the subscriber interface. See http://cs.unc.edu/~dewan/comp114/s09/Class%20Notes/15_MVC_Notes.pdf

Comment: I do have a controller, I just thought that my model and view would only be interacting when it came to buttons, although I honestly don't what code goes where and so many people say so many different things. Thanks for the reading material though! :)

Comment: Do you have an example though of how you call a function with MVC style code?

Comment: Your view and model never interact directly. Your controller calls a function on the model, which contains your business logic, then the controller passes this data to the view.

Comment: See this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/mvc_pattern.htm

Answer (score 0):

MVC would dictate that the "controller" will seed the "view" with data from the "model", so it would suggest that your "controller" needs to read the data from the "model" and pass it to the "view", this means that the view will need to provide some means for the "controller" to pass data to it, how exactly is up to you, but may by providing a `setInfo` method.

One thing I might focus on is ensuring that the "view" doesn't expose the UI elements directly, as the "controller" shouldn't care "how" the UI is implemented, only that it provides an appropriate contract through which the "controller" and "view" can communicate.

Also, Swing is already a MVC, so be careful trying to put another MVC on top of it, it tends to lead to a lot of other issues.